# What is the scope of a static object in a web application

Tags: java, servlets, javabeans

I have an application that consists of an HTML form and a Servlet that Creates a new object from the parameters submitted by the user, then adds the created bean to a list.

There is the JavaBean class:

```
public class Client{

private String name, adress, tel, email;

public Client(String name, String adress, String tel, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.adress = adress;
    this.tel = tel;
    this.email = email;
}

//A bunch of Getters and Setters
}
```

Here is the ClientsMan class:

```
public abstract class ClientsMan {

private static List<Client> clientsList;

static
{
    clientsList= new ArrayList<Client>();
}

public static void addClient(Client c)
{
    clientsList.add(c);
}
}
```

Here is the doPost() method of the servlet that handles the form:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //Getting the parametres
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String adress = request.getParameter("adress");
    String tel = request.getParameter("tel");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    //Creating a Client object from the user inputs
    Client client = new Client(name, adress, tel, email);

    //Adding the bean in an arrayList
    ClientsMan.addClient(client);

}
```

I will need to keep a list of all the clients added for later use.

**My question is:** 
What is the scope of the List in my application, is it a request scope or an Application Scope?
Will I lose my list after the user quits the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the scope of the List in my application, is it a request scope
>   or an Application Scope?

None of them because its lifecycle is not managed by your application, the `List` `clientsList` is a `static` field of the class `ClientsMan` which means that it is rather scoped to the `ClassLoader` that initialized the class `ClientsMan` which should exist even after the user quits the application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you please provide me with some more informations about this issue, is it wrong that I made the List static?

What will be it's behavior if let's say the application could be accessed by different users

Comment: all your clients will share the same `List`

Answer (score 1):

The static class is not a bean as it is not container-managed, so there is not any scope related to this class.
Your `List`will still exist when user will quit your application.

Also you should manage, if needed, thread-safety of your list.

Comment: too late, @Nicolas Filotto gave you the answer

Comment: I noticed that, I will change the title to 'static object'

Answer (score 1):

The default scope of object will be request scope. Any variable instantiated in a service method will have request scope. And every request and response pair is a part of thread that starts with a service and ends when that service class ends.

That being said as outlined the list is a static type, so it will last until the JVM. But you will face issues while running it since it is not a thread safe object. you need to make the static block snychronized.